# Настройка htaccess для запуска проекта на laravel на хостинге с ssl сертификатом

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

Как правильно настроить htaccess для запуска проекта на laravel на обычном хостинге с редиректом на https?
В корневом `.htaccess` указываю

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

При заходе на сайт, все работает(в урл не нужно прописывать /public)
Встала задача сделать редирект с http на https

Пробовал в файле `/public/.htaccess` прописать

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Но теперь при заходе на сайт, он редиректит с `http://site.ru` на `https://site.ru/public`

upd

Есть сдвиг, в файле `/public/.htaccess` прописать

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Front-End-Https} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Теперь при переходе на `http` редиректит на `https`
Но есть проблема:

При переходе по `http://site.ru/name` он редиретит на `https://site.ru/index.php`, то есть при редиректе 'pathname' не сохраняется

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` Так попробуйте

Comment: @InDevX Все равно, он редиректит с `http://site.ru` на `https://site.ru/public` - `Сайт site.ru выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.`

Comment: Вообще, по-хорошему бы, настроить надо сервер и обработку делать только в 1 .htaccess